# HashMap synchronisation

Tags: java

I have a map and i am synchronising it in between.Will there be any difference in behaviour of the map in insertion after the synchronisation?

```
HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
myMap.put("abc","123");
myMap.put("efg","456");
Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);
myMap.put("hij","789");
myMap.put("jkl","234");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The insertions after calling `Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);` would be thread safe, insertions before would not be thread safe. All `Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);` does is wrap your map object in a thread-safe `SynchronizedMap` object. Other than that there is no difference.

Also, you need to change the code to `myMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);`

Answer (score 4):

```
<K, V> Map<K, V> java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap(Map<K, V> m)
```

Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) map backed by the specified map. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing map is accomplished through the returned map.

It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
   ...
Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
  ...
synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
  Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
  while (i.hasNext())
      foo(i.next());
}
```

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

The returned map will be serializable if the specified map is serializable.

Parameters:
    m the map to be "wrapped" in a synchronized map.
Returns:
    a synchronized view of the specified map.

Answer (score 2):

It will behave exactly like the map before it, except it will be synchronized. You must use the return value of `Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);` though as the parameter `myMap` will not be altered.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the ConcurrentHashMap from java.util.concurrent ?

Basically, this is more-or-less a drop in replacement for the HashMap, but is thread-safe when correctly used, has additional guaranteed-atomic methods for certain tasks and is lock-free (by exploiting the properties of a reasonable hashing function) in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

No difference.

`Collections.synchronizedMap()` just **forwards** the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);
```

you have ignored the return value.
   Use as

```
   Map syncMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap); // wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `HashMap` is not synchronized so inserting elements from concurrent threads yields undefined results. Using a synchronized map prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` creates a new synchronized map backed by the map you pass in argument. It therefore does NOT synchronize the map `myMap`.